# Where is MemStorage and Contour classes Emgu 4.2

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

Where is MemStorage and Contour classes Emgu 4.2

I try to port this example to up to date:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/emguexample/

Comment: Reading the documentation would be a great start http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/a0649fd8-44db-705d-04f6-147f35e7892c.htm and here http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/f0b496b6-fa5d-6e60-b2ae-41cb1e54d396.htm

Comment: Version 1.3 is only 12 years old. I am asking version 4.2

Comment: Then search for the documentation?

Comment: I tryed no result. I find it version 1,2,3. Until they make api remake and mess up version 4.

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.1/document/html/8dee1f02-8c8a-4e37-87f4-05e10c39f27d.htm that's the latest I see.

Answer (score 0):

`MemStorage` and `Contour` classes were removed between Emgu version 3.0.0-rc1 and 3.0.0:

- commit hash corresponding to `MemStorage` removal: [b7ea29f](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/commit/b7ea29f468926834353d0a135b2e90c7f4bb0804)
- commit hash corresponding to `Contour` removal: [c61c55b](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/commit/c61c55bc16d514c04d4400aa7e6e1f24e6ec6bc7)

It is not mentioned in the [3.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#version30).

`Contour` (output of `CvInvoke.FindContours` method) can now be expressed as a [Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.8.1/document/html/T_Emgu_CV_Util_VectorOfVectorOfPoint.htm)